# WPF Combobox Itemssource is Visibility Enum

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

So i have a simple question; I want to display the `System.Windows.Visibility` Enum in a ComboBox. However i don't seem to find the path to it. Searched like a crazy man but couldn't find anyone who know the path to this enum.

I'm aware that this can be done in code (and already have it working) but i prefer to do it in XAML.

Could anyone help me out?

Answer (score 3):

Voila:

```
<ComboBox SelectedIndex="0">
       <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
       <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
       <Visibility>Hidden</Visibility>
</ComboBox>
```

No additional namespaces needed.

Answer (score 0):

@Maciek's solution is the simplest and quickest to apply, however more general, pure *XAML* way of listing enum values is this:

```
<FrameworkElement.Resources>
    <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="ItemsSource"
                        ObjectType="{x:Type sys:Enum}"
                        MethodName="GetValues"
                        xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
        <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
            <x:Type TypeName="Visibility" />
        </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
    </ObjectDataProvider>
</FrameworkElement.Resources>
(...)
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ItemsSource}}" />
```

You can then simply replace `Visibility` with any other enum type to get a list of its values.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to bind enum values to ItemsSource, you need a property in ViewModel with enum values. Than you have to bind ItemsSource to this property. You get values of enum like this:

```
Enum.GetValues(typeof(EffectStyle)).Cast<EffectStyle>();
```

If you can't find a path to your property, that means you have wrong DataContext. Set it to your ViewModel class or to your window, if your are not using MVVM. In the simplest scenario, you could set DataContext to your window in Window constructor.

```
this.DataContext = this;
```

Take a look at [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/321899/DataContext-in-WPF) or [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-binding-wpf) link, as a big picture of DataContext and Binding in WPF.
If you are interested, also read about MVVM in WPF. You could use [MVVM Light](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/getting-started-with-mvvm-light-with-wpf/)

If you want a fully xaml solution for your enum binding to ComboBox, you could write sth like [this](http://brianlagunas.com/a-better-way-to-data-bind-enums-in-wpf/) or use `ObjectDataProvider` like [here](http://www.devcurry.com/2011/03/wpf-4-using-objectdataprovider-for.html).
I think Maciek's solution is good enough in your case.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it using code, let's say your combobx has an x:name = my combo you can simply do:

```
mycombo.ItemsSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Visibility)).Cast<Visibility>();
```